# Select all text in TextBox for all textboxes in app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I would like to have all the textboxes in my Windows 10 universal app to automaticly select all the text when they are focused.  Much like this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38212/How-can-you-add-Select-All-behaviour-for-all-TextB) (WPF).  Is this possible in UWP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it with attached behavior using `AttachedProperty`

Like this: A class to hold the property which is of type `bool` and on change is attaching/detaching handler for the focus event

```
public static class TextBoxAttached
{
    public static bool GetAutoSelectable(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AutoSelectableProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutoSelectable(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AutoSelectableProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoSelectableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AutoSelectable",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TextBoxAttached),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, AutoFocusableChangedHandler));

    private static void AutoFocusableChangedHandler(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
        {
            if((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            {
                (d as TextBox).GotFocus += OnGotFocusHandler;
            }
            else
            {
                (d as TextBox).GotFocus -= OnGotFocusHandler;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnGotFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Usage: XAML

```
<TextBox Text="Test" local:TextBoxAttached.AutoSelectable="True"/>
```

**EDIT**

You could define also a default style to make all your `TextBox`es be auto selectable

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" >
        <Setter Property="local:TextBoxAttached.AutoSelectable" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: I like the idea!  I'll try it out Monday.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to accomplish this, but here's one: just extend the existing TextBox control and use that one everywhere.

```
public class SelectableTextBox : TextBox
{
    public SelectableTextBox()
    {
        this.GotFocus += SelectableTextBox_GotFocus;
    }

    private void SelectableTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:SelectableTextBox Text="This is some text."/>
```

Here's one other way. Write a behavior!

```
public class SelectAllTextBoxBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    private TextBox textBox;

    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textBox;
        }
    }

    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        if (associatedObject is TextBox)
        {
            this.textBox = associatedObject as TextBox;
            this.textBox.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
        }
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        if (this.textBox != null)
        {
            this.textBox.GotFocus -= TextBox_GotFocus;
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

And attach it to every TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text="This is some text.">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

You will need the Behaviors SDK added to your project for the second option to work.